# How to overload operator `in`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading, operators, grammar

How can I overload operator `in` on the premise that I have used `__getitem__` for operator `[]` in the class I defined?

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.slots = [None]*5

    def __setitem__(self, key, data):
        self.set(key, data)

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.get(key)

    def set(self, key, data):
        self.slots[key]=data

    def get(self,key):
        return self.slots[key]

s=myClass()
s[0]='first'
s[1]='second'
print(s[0])#<-------first
print(s.slots)#<----['first', 'second', None, None, None]
```

How can I implement the function with `in` like that?

```
print(('second' in s))#<----True
print(('third' in s))#<-----False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in` operator will call to the `__contains__` magic method.
See [https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**contains**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)

Comment: Amazing! Ur answer is so swift, efficient and exact!! Thank U!!!

Answer (score 0):

No need for that, if you try:

```
"second" in ["first", "second"]
```

it is going to return True just as you want